# Using Javascript to get current Browser and print on HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Basically I'm new to JavaScript and for my website I found a website detection code that is done by duck typing and I need to implement a feature where it prints the specific browser someone is using and I don't understand how I would go about doing it.

Here's the code: https://jsfiddle.net/311aLtkz/ (found code on stack overflow)

```
var output = 'Detecting browsers by ducktyping:<hr>';
output += 'isFirefox: ' + isFirefox + '<br>';
output += 'isChrome: ' + isChrome + '<br>';
output += 'isSafari: ' + isSafari + '<br>';
output += 'isOpera: ' + isOpera + '<br>';
output += 'isIE: ' + isIE + '<br>';
output += 'isEdge: ' + isEdge + '<br>';
output += 'isBlink: ' + isBlink + '<br>';
document.body.innerHTML = output;
```

Question is that how would I implement a feature that it would print the browser being used as a text in html.

Comment: seriously what is the question?

Comment: You forgot the part where you describe a problem and ask a question...

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why not just use the straightforward approach and check each `isXXX` variable in an if-statement?

Comment: but the code is already doing that... you only need to stop printing all names and print only when a browser is True

Comment: `document.body.innerHTML = output;` print the browser being used in as text html

Comment: but its not printing in the html file though

Comment: For me it's printing... no errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are currently adding every word to the final `output` by using `+=` without using an `if` statement to check which one is the right browser.

You should use an `if`, so if the browser is `Chrome` for example, then you add it's name to the `output` variable. 
Here, every `is...` (`isChrome`, `isFirefox`, etc...) variable is receiving a true or false value that can be checked.

Take a look, is that what you want?

**EDIT 2019**

Accordlying to MDN, using `navigator` you can now print the Browser name with a simple function:

```js
function GetBrowser() {
  var aKeys = ["MSIE", "Firefox", "Safari", "Chrome", "Opera"];
  var sUsrAg = navigator.userAgent;
  var nIdx = aKeys.length - 1;
  
  while(nIdx > -1 && sUsrAg.indexOf(aKeys[nIdx]) === -1){
    nIdx--;
  }  

  var browserStr = "Unknown";
  if (nIdx > -1){
    browserStr = aKeys[nIdx]
  }

  document.getElementById("browser_info").textContent = browserStr;
  return browserStr;
}

GetBrowser();
```

```css
#browser_info{
  font-size: 18px;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
Current Browser: <span id="browser_info"></span>
```

Old version:

```js
// Opera 8.0+
var isOpera = (!!window.opr && !!opr.addons) || !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;

// Firefox 1.0+
var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';

// Safari 3.0+ "[object HTMLElementConstructor]" 
var isSafari = /constructor/i.test(window.HTMLElement) || (function (p) { return p.toString() === "[object SafariRemoteNotification]"; })(!window['safari'] || safari.pushNotification);

// Internet Explorer 6-11
var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;

// Edge 20+
var isEdge = !isIE && !!window.StyleMedia;

// Chrome 1+
var isChrome = !!window.chrome && (!!window.chrome.webstore || !!window.chrome.runtime);

// Blink engine detection
var isBlink = (isChrome || isOpera) && !!window.CSS;

var output = 'Detecting browsers by ducktyping:<hr>Browser: ';
if (isFirefox){
  output += 'FIREFOX';
}else if(isChrome){
  output +=  'CHROME';
}else if(isSafari){
  output +=  'SAFARI';
}else if(isOpera){
  output +=  'OPERA';
}else if(isIE){
  output +=  'I.E';
}else if(isEdge){
  output +=  'EDGE';
}

if (isBlink){
  output += " (Blink)";
}
document.body.innerHTML = output;
```

Comment: have you runned the snippet, it's doing exactly that, only the browser you are using. (please, if it is the correct answer, mark it as accepted, in the mark below the 'downvote')

Comment: If you are talking about the other text besides the browser name, just remove it from the output variable, it is the most basic thing to learn and do yourself

Comment: @Billy More clearly describe what the output is, and what you want to change, and we can better help.